# Page Speed Insight Tool: Desktop Score Available, but Mobile Score Unavailable after Laravel Backend Migration

Tags: pagespeed, lighthouse, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I've recently updated a website, migrating the backend to the PHP Laravel framework. However, I've encountered an issue with the Page Speed Insight tool – it provides a Desktop score but doesn't generate a mobile score.

Despite searching on Google, I haven't found anyone else facing this problem. I've already looked at the robots.txt file, which only contains the default template from Laravel:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Link to the PageSpeed report:

https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-www-runningteameindhoven-nl/2sx3tkdt3r

And here are the screenshots:

[image: Mobile]

[image: Desktop]